# query relation always null with model_type value single slash Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a trouble with relationship on laravel 9 with code detail below:

```
namespace App\Models;
use App\Traits\HasMeta
class PostModel extends Model{
   use HasMeta;
}

namespace App\Traits;
use App\Models\MetaModel;
trait HasMeta{
  public function meta() {
        return $this->morphOne(MetaModel::class, 'metas', 'model_type', 'model_id') ;
   }
}
```

And my schemas is:

```
+---------------------+-------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type                    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+-------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | bigint(20) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| model_id            | int(11)                 | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| model_type          | varchar(255)            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| meta_slug           | varchar(255)            | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| meta_title          | varchar(255)            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| meta_description    | text                    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| meta_keywords       | text                    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| meta_canonical      | varchar(255)            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| meta_index          | enum('index','noindex') | NO   |     | noindex |                |
| meta_og_title       | varchar(255)            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| meta_og_description | text                    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| meta_tw_title       | varchar(255)            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| meta_tw_description | text                    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at          | timestamp               | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at          | timestamp               | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+-------------------------+------+-----+---------+--------------
```

But when i used method $post->meta()->save(array $data) -> it's ok and insert to database with value

```
+----+----------+----------------------+
| id | model_id | model_type           |
+----+----------+----------------------+
|  1 |       83 | App\Models\PostModel |
+----+----------+----------------------+
```

However when i used $post->meta --> it always return null.

My sql laravel output:

```
select * from `ord_metas` where `ord_metas`.`model_id` in (83) and `ord_metas`.`model_type` = 'App\Models\PostModel'
```

If model_type with double slash like 'App\\Models\\PostModel' --> it will be ok on mysql query

How can i fix it. Thank for reading and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Make a method inside the MetaModel like

```
public function metable ()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

and make another method inside your trait or postModel like

```
  public function meta()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(MetaModel::class , 'metable');
    }
```

Now you can load the relationship as   `$post->meta`   Hope this helps you.